# ios 7.0 upgrade issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I have iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3 which is recently upgraded to iOS 7 now I need to test my app on that iPhone with iOS 7. I have SDK Xcode 4.6 and OS X 10.7.5

I got some small issues here due to iOS 6.1.3 upgrade to iOS 7:

> 1. I'm unable to test my app on that iPhone 4 with my current SDK (Xcode 4.6). So, if I need to update it to Xcode 5.0 but its not
>      working with OS X 10.7.5.
> 2. If I upgraded my OS X 10.7.5 to 10.8.5 will it work?
> 3. I have tried to downgrade iOS but I'm unable to do that because Apple stopped the signing for the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade your X-code version 5 and after upgrading u test your app in your phone

Answer (score 0):

First you need to upgrade your mac os to 10.8 then only you can install xcode 5. From xcode 5 you can take build in the device which is having IOS 7.

For your reference :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW1

Answer (score 0):

First of you have to upgrade your SDK' to to Xcode 5,IOS7 ....In the deployment target please use IOS 6 or relatively your iPhones IOS...Please remember developemnt target and deployment target are different....

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so].  Could you provide some more information as to why this solves the issue?  This will help in improving the quality of your question, which is likely to lead to upvotes (which in turn gets you more reputation).  Thanks!